# How to make ASP.NET AJAX CalendarExtender always visible?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, calendar, asp.net-3.5, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'd like to be able to have the .NET AJAX CalendarExtender show on Load without having to click in a TextBox. If I can simulate a TextBox being clicked so the CalendarExtender will show I'll take that too.

Answer (score 2):

The CalendarExtender does not support it.  You could write your own, but it would be much simpler to just use a standard [Calendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar%28VS.80%29.aspx) control if you want a calendar that's always visible.

The extender was meant for use with a textbox when you want the calendar to pop up as needed.  Why write a new control when the basic control already exists?

**Edit**

To address the point in the comment about needing to switch years easily.  I COMPELTELY understand.  This is a frustration for me as well.  however, there are several ways to overcome this.  One good example can be found here: https://web.archive.org/web/20210304123649/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/090104-1.aspx

Comment: Because the basic control doesn't show all 12 months in one control. The basic control only shows the days of one month. I need to be able to switch between days of the month and months in the year.

Comment: @dotnetB00b - Good point, although there are a number of ways to get around this.  One good article can be found here: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/090104-1.aspx

Comment: B00b... lol. Well, the CalendarExtender can show all 12 months in one control. And also you can switch to show all the days in a particular month. I'd like that kind of functionality. That's why I was hoping to somehow trick the CalendarExtender to be visible.

Comment: Sorry. Typo "B" key right next to "N" key... FUNNY typo, but still, it was a mistake. I think I'll go home for the day now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" />


  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtboxFilter" ClientIDMode="Static" />
  <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="txtboxFilter" />


    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById('txtboxFilter').focus();
    </script>
```